# Can't install SQL Management Studio 2008 R2 Express - Throws exception

Tags: installation, sql-server-2008-r2

I am running SQL Server 2008 R2 on a Windows Server 2012 R2 machine. `select @@version` returns the following string:

> Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP2) - 10.50.4000.0 (Intel X86)
>           Jun 28 2012 08:42:37
>           Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
>           Express Edition on Windows NT 6.2  (Build 9200: ) (WOW64) (Hypervisor)

I don't know how the installation made it's way on this server. Anyway I am trying to configure the Express Edition using Management Studio. I know I can add the feature via Control Panel, however I don't have the original installer package, so no luck there.

That's why I went to the [Microsoft site](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=30438) and downloaded `SQLManagementStudio_x64_ENU.exe`. But the installation keeps throwing this .NET exception.

> An error occured creating the configuration section handler for
>   userSettings/Microsoft.SQLServer.Configuration.LandingPage.Properties.Settings:
>   Could not load file or assembly 'System, Version=4.0.0.0
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=.....? or one of its dependencies. The
>   system cannot find the file specified.
>   (C:\Users\myUsers\AppData\Local\Microsoft_Corporation\LandingPage.exe_StrongName_ryspccglaxmt4nhdfas[...]\10.0.0.0\user.confi

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for the noise, I have figured it out by myself in the meantime. The only thing that needs to be done is to delete the following file:

`C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Microsoft_Corporation\LandingPage.exe_StrongName_ryspccglaxmt4nhllj5z3thycltsvyyx\10.0.0.0\user.config`

Then restart the installation process and you're good!